# Filling Dynamic Array

Tags: php, arrays

how can i fill following type array dynamically in for loop

```
$trans2 = array(); 
$username = array("John","Steve"); 
$categories = arra("cat1","cat2","cat3");
```

result must be:

```
[0] => Array ( [Name] => John [cat1] => 0 [cat2] => 0 [cat3] => 0 )

[1] => Array
(
    [Name] => Smith
    [cat1] => 0
    [cat2] => 0
    [cat3] => 0
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I truly don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Where do you take those names? What's `$trans2`? What have you tried? Please clarify your question.

Comment: trans2 array is result array.

Comment: I fail to see how 'John' and 'Steve' become 'John' and 'Smith'

Comment: You must have tried *something* haven't you?

Comment: that's my mistake... Smith should be Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($username as $name)
{
   foreach($categories as $cat)
   {
      $trans2[$name][$cat] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: @user812129: Note that it does not exactly produce the array you wanted, though it might be an even better structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
foreach($username as $key=>$name){
  $trans2[$key]['name'] = $name;
  foreach($categories as $cat){
    $trans2[$key][$cat] = 0;
  }
}
```